# How to detect which button is pressed in windows form message box?

Tags: c++, messagebox, windows

In my windows form application,I want to prompt to user to restart the PC. This is my code:

```
 if(MessageBox::Show(L"Restart your PC now?", "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, MessageBoxIcon::Question)==::DialogResult::Yes)
{
//restarting pc
     system("c:\\windows\\system32\\shutdown /r /t 10 \n\n");
     system("PAUSE");
}
```

But this code give me error at ::DialogResult::Yes. I'm following Microsoft documentation. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Guessing...

It looks like this is .NET code (albeit in C++) in this case the `DialogResult` type is not defined at global scope, but in the `System::Windows::Forms` namespace. So, remove the leading `::` (or fully qualify it as `System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult`).

Also note, that there are APIs to restart windows [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`InitiateShutdownEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874(v=vs.85).aspx). No need to invoke an external program.